# Passing data as JSON from PHP to Python

Tags: python, php, json

Php code for running python script with json data:

```
$output = shell_exec("python php_test.py " . base64_encode(json_encode($process_data)) . " 2>&1");
```

Python code for decoding json:

```
jdata = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
```

This is how $process_data looks like:

```
array (size=15)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Güvenlik amaçlarına giriş", "en":"Introduction to Security Goals."}' (length=78)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Kriptografinin Matematiği.", "en":"Mathematics of Cryptography."}' (length=73)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Geleneksel Simetrik Anahtarlı Şifreler.", "en":"Traditional Symmetric Key Ciphers."}' (length=93)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Cebirsel Yapılar.", "en":"Algebraic Structures."}' (length=57)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Modern Simetrik Anahtarlı Şifrelere Giriş.", "en":"Introduction to Modern Symmetric Key Ciphers."}' (length=108)
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Gelişmiş Şifreleme Standardı.", "en":"Advanced Encryption Standard."}' (length=80)
  6 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Modern Simetrik Anahtarlı Şifrelerle Şifreleme.", "en":"Encipherment Using Modern Symmetric-Key Ciphers."}' (length=116)
  7 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Stream Ciphers", "en":"Akan Şifreleme Yöntemleri."}' (length=60)
  8 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Ara Sınav", "en":"Midterm Exam"}' (length=40)
  9 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Doğrusal ve Diferansiyel Kriptanaliz.", "en":"Linear and DifferentialCryptanalysis."}' (length=93)
  10 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Kriptografik Özet Fonsiyonları.", "en":"Cryptographic Hash Functions."}' (length=80)
  11 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Asimetrik Kriptoloji", "en":"Asymmetric Cryptography"}' (length=61)
  12 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Protokollar, Tcp/Ip Protokol ve Hizmetlerinde Güvenlik", "en":"Protocols, Security in Tcp/Ip Networks"}' (length=111)
  13 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Güvenlik Duvarları ve Sanal Özel Ağlar", "en":"Firewall and Virtual Private Networking"}' (length=99)
  14 => 
    array (size=1)
      'konu' => string '{"tr":"Saldırı Tespit Sistemleri", "en":"Intrusion Detection Systems"}' (length=72)
```

I'm getting a decoder error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0131' in
>   position 33: character maps to < undefined>

When I remove base64_encode, I get "Expecting ',' delimiter" error instead.

I'm guessing it is caused by the double-quotes. How can I escape them?

Comment: what error are you getting exactly? Does it work without base64 encoding?

Comment: can you post an example of the json? maybe it doesnt have a proper array at the root. It would be helpful to see the error

Comment: the output of $process_data looks weird, do you really want a json string in the "konu" index or an actual associative array?

Comment: @fromvega as much as I'd prefer an associative array, I get $process_data from a PHP API, it isn't my doing and I have to send it to Python. If you have suggestions on how I could fix it up, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an encoding issue on the python side of things, possibly due to a difference in encoding between your PHP script and what you have set in python.

It seems that the json encoder/decoder in python needs JSON to be represented using either UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32, with UTF-8 being the recommended default for maximum interoperability. Can you confirm that everything on the PHP side is UTF-8?

Here is the source:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#character-encodings

Answer (score 0):

Change character encoding for MS windows console to utf-8 by entering the following command

chcp 65001

Now run your script again.